# Проблема на Chrome с border-image и SVG

Tags: html, html5, svg, google-chrome

Применяю SVG с закругленными краями во внутрь как border для элементов. То что обвел красным по какой-то причине этот просвет виден только на chrome и на разных экранах. Можно это как то убрать эффект ?[Ссылка на источник проблемы](https://hfood.lexweb.studio/product-category/korm/kormi-dlya-sobak/)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @UModeL  Чертов гений :) It's work !!

Answer (score 1):

Хотя в Chrome уже давно ввели `border-image`, оно отличается от реализации версии с префиксом.

Попробуйте для *Chrome* использовать `-webkit-border-image` принудительно (в том варианте, как у Вас сейчас, более новое свойство - `border-image` - стоит ниже, чем `-webkit-border-image` и перебивает его).